# I would like to use the 'facebook graph api' to import the facebook posts of all the members who have logged in facebook on our platform

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good morning.
Because my native language is not English, the grammar of my writing can be somewhat wrong. I beg you to ask for your understanding.

Currently, I am trying to get the member's posts and related information through the information of the member who logged in to Facebook from the platform that our company is developing.

However, if I test myself with 'me / feed' or 'me / posts' in the facebook api explorer provided by Facebook,
On my test homepage I get no value and I do not even get an error.

I understand that this issue is not authorized by the Facebook company to implement this feature.
So I tried 'app verification' to get permission, but the project is not completed yet and I can not input what I want to submit.
However, in order to receive the permission, the actual page process of the project should be shown as a movie.

So far, you will understand what my current problem is.

We need facebook_graph_api to complete our project.
But I have a question.
Are you sure that if you receive the "user_posts" from my Facebook app at https://developers.facebook.com/, will you actually be able to import posts from other members?

Comment: First of all, regarding development vs review, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: _“Are you sure that if you receive the "user_posts" from my Facebook app at https://developers.facebook.com/, will you actually be able to import posts from other members?”_ - anything not clear about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_posts …?

Answer (score -2):

yes ,you would be able to import public posts of other members

For that you need to first authenticate and get credentials
you can get posts of members,likes ,comments using FQL queries.

Comment: fql is deprecated since many years...and this would be much better as a comment, to be honest.